# Is the definite article used before the comparative adjective?

Tags: grammar

Today, I noticed an example in Collin dictionary online the following sentence:

> She looks the happier for her trip.

I checked in Google Ngram once as "she looks happy for ..." and once "she looks happier for..." No result I got for "she looks happier"

With whom we compare her? Perhaps she looks happier than other her two sisters.

> ADVERB
>
> 1. (often foll by for) used before comparative adjectives or adverbs for emphasis
>
> she looks the happier for her trip

Answer (score 2):

This a normal, if perhaps uncommon, use of "the". Merriam-Webster gives [this definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the):

> **the** adverb
> **Definition of *the* (Entry 2 of 4)**
> 1: than before : than otherwise —used before a comparative
> // none *the* wiser for attending

By the way, "for" in this sentence means "because of". Therefore, your sentence means:

> She looks happier than before because of her trip.
> She looks happier than [[she would have looked]] otherwise because of her trip.

This meaning of "the" often appears in other constructions, some of which are idiomatic. For example:

> "All **the better** to see you with," the Wolf replied.
> The stock is cheap. That is all **the more** reason to buy it now.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence

> She looks the happier for her trip.

is using a correct but somewhat old-fashioned form  It means that she looks happier than she did before the trip, and implies that the trip is the cause of this change.